# Mounting a remote volume

Tags: cocoa, osx-mountain-lion

I am trying to mount a remote disk in Cocoa but I am unable to find any method to do so.

A number of place I've looked have reccomended using [this API](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/Reference/reference.html), however, almost all of it is depreciated by 10.8 and I am targeting 10.8.

The drive I am trying to mount is a Microsoft Sharepoint file server (it's not local but I presume it uses SMB?).

What is the recommended method to to this?

Comment: Did you try the replacement that's recommended in the document you linked to?

Comment: It links to NSUrl and CFURL, which isn't very helpful. I've tried searching both documentations for it.

Comment: The documentation of the specific File Manager functions for your task include a more specific recommendation of a replacement.

Comment: Could you site an API? After a goof amount of time looking I am yet to find a suitable way.

Comment: “To mount a network volume, use NetFSMountURLAsync instead (to cancel a pending mount request, use NetFSMountURLCancel). For more information, see NetFS.h in /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Headers.)”